# How can I get HTMLPREFIX inside the partial view i Razor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I'm in need of getting the Html Prefix inside the partial view.

I've got a prefix like this attached to where I render my partial view

```
 Html.RenderPartial("Person", Model.Person, new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData)
{
    TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "DelegatePerson"}
});
```

Now when I go in to the Person PartialView
I need the prefix in a situation like this.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CPR, new { @class = "numericTextbox", maxlength = 10, id = "CprField", onkeyup ="CprFieldEdited("[HTMLPrefix]_FieldName");" })
```

however I don't know how to do so. and I've been searching for a long time now. 
I hope someone knows how to do this or something similar.

**EDIT:**

this means I should be able to tell the Javascript function CprFieldEdited that the html prefix it should search for is in this case "DelegatePerson"

**Edit 2:**
It seems it is not clear what I mean so I'll try to provide some more code.

Main Page:

```
 //None relevant Code here
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/person_search")
//None relevant Code here
        <Body>
    //None relevant Code here
               Html.RenderPartial("Person", Model.Person, new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData)
               {
                   TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "DelegatePerson"}
               });
        //None relevant Code here
               Html.RenderPartial("Person", Model.Person, new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData)
               {
                   TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "EmployerPerson"}
               });
        //None relevant Code here
            </body>
```

in this scenario I've got two Partials of the same type that are rendered on the same page. However inside them I need to tell the Javascript bundles which one of them is being used now as I cannot use the ID's they are being used for something else my idea what to use the Name attribute with the prefix however as the next code shows I can't give the javascript the prefix it's in to differentiated between the two partials

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CPR, new {id = "CprField", onkeyup ="CprFieldEdited("[FieldNameWithPartialPrefix]");" })
```

the problem is I cannot give the CprFieldEdited("[FieldNameWithPartialPrefix]"); javascript the "[FieldNameWithPartialPrefix]" which could be either "DelegatePerson_Fieldname" or "EmployerPerson"

Comment: yes the Javascript will need the prefix to differentiate between the partial on the main page and the partial in another partial on the main page.
if that made any sense at all

Comment: You don't need to pass an `HtmlFieldPrefix` for that. Just do `ViewBag.CustomPrefix = "your_prefix";`

Comment: Ahh Now I found the solution you where right @rae1n I've set the Viewbag in the main page and use it in the partial page. it's so simple I just didn't realize it. Thanks a lot. I'll mark your answer as the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to pass a prefix using the `HtmlFieldPrefix`. You could just pass it using `ViewBag` (which works similar to `ViewData`, but it more recommended).

Just do,

```
 @Html.RenderPartial(
     "Person", 
     Model.Person, 
     new ViewDataDictionary()
         {
              { "Custom Prefix", "your_prefix" }
         });
```

Alternatively, you could define your prefix in the partial,

```
@{
    ViewBag.CustomPrefix = "your_prefix";
}
```

And to access it either way, just do,

```
<a onkeyup="@ViewBag.CustomPrefix"> ... </a>
```

You could use `ViewBag` to pass anything as it is `dynamic`. For more [info](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem).

Comment: well yes I can do this but I wouldn't be activating my Javascript then 
onkeyup ="CprFieldEdited("[HTMLPrefix]_FieldName");"
which still need a way to differentiate between the same Partial two places on the same page.

Comment: I posted a comment regarding that. Can you be more specific as to what you need to do? Why do you need the `HtmlFieldPrefix`? If you need to differentiate between two partials, why can't you pick it up from the partial name?

Comment: because if I don't give it a prefix and get the prefix in the javascript I would have to make two javascript that does the same for the same task to different places which isn't what I want. 

I might make the Javascript a little clumsy but it works now I just need to make sure it works more generic. 

however I see your comment now with the viewbag.CustomPrefix and I just have one question for that is it posible to set in the page that uses the partials so each partial will know where they come from. 

I'm sorry if I'm not clear my first language is not english so it's quite difficult for me.

Comment: @Helbo I updated the answer to show what you requested. And if it helps, don't forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
((System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary)(ViewData)).TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
```

Comment: Or more currently now, using Razor to access in the partial view ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary)(ViewData)).TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;